# Using Table A as a flag for Table B

Tags: sql, informix

I'm using Informix to create a table that is to act like a flag for other apps and tables. The table I created has these columns: a unique sequential number, table_name, app, value (Y/N), check_name (what is being verified). So for example if the value is checked 'Y' for table enrollment and app error_check.

Then I want to run that script associated with that app. The idea is to be able to turn on and off certain scripts to run, so we can easily find errors and let people know about it. I currently have to put a conditional in the actual application SQL script to match against the table I created and that seems redundant and I don't want to add the conditional to all the code we are going to use. I was thinking maybe I could have the script create some sort of temp table when comparing the conditional table to the table I want to check against. Then maybe I create an app with just some basic drop down boxes to check Y/N values and what I want to check.

So I guess my question will be: am I looking at this all wrong? And what kind of way should I try to make a conditional.

### Example of conditional I'm using in SQL

```
WHERE 'Y' = (SELECT value
               FROM err_table
              WHERE app = 'progerr' AND check_name = 'CLASS_VALIDATION');
```

Comment: Can you just use a View which filters the dataset as needed?

Comment: [Create view in Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0642.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're doing, but surely you should put appropriate check constraints on the columns in the tables so that invalid values are rejected.  If you need different validation on the values in a column depending on which application is manipulating the data, then you're probably in for a world of hurt — you should review your design.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll look into making a View for now.